# loop based on user input java

Tags: java, user-input

I want to write a program that queries the user for a "number n" and then output the word repetition n times.
For example the word is "Hello".

So far I've got this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); 

        System.out.println("Zahl 1:");
        int number = scanner.nextInt();



    }
```

Which should end in this ->

Number: 3
Hello
Hello 
Hell
.

I don't know how to move forward.

I thank you for your time in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code out print "Hallo" n times (n = numbers)

```
 String s = "Hello";
 for (int i = 0; i < number; i++){
      System.out.println(s);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use functional programming.

```
IntStream.range(0, n)
           .forEach(System.out.println(variable));
```

Here n is the number of times that string is to be printed and a variable is a string.